# Yii displays standard error even in debug mode

Tags: php, debugging, yii, stack-trace

I have a bug in my `CGridView`. One of the columns tries to read a property from non object. Just before line, that renders this grid view (i.e. just above `<?php $this->widget('GridView', array (`) I placed following code:

```
<?php
    echo 'YII_DEBUG = '.print_r(YII_DEBUG, TRUE);
    var_dump(YII_DEBUG);
    echo 'YII_TRACE_LEVEL = '.print_r(YII_TRACE_LEVEL, TRUE);
    var_dump(YII_TRACE_LEVEL);
    die();
?>
```

And it gives me following results:

```
YII_DEBUG = 1
bool(true)
YII_TRACE_LEVEL = 3
int(3)
```

However, when I remove or comment-out this code, the very next line (where error occurs) does not causes Yii to render typical, full-stack debug information (including file, line and stack trace) about error. Instead, I see a one-line error message, rendered with `site/error` view, just as I should see it, when debug would actually be turned off (but, it isn't):

[image]

I've been struggling with this for months, but I have no cluse, what can cause Yii to ignore debug settings and display errors without debug stack trace even, when debug mode is enabled.

Can anyone help here, by at least giving some tip, where should I start to look for?

Comment: Maybe there are more infos inside the log files on apache?

Comment: How could that be relevant? Yii error handling works just perfectly. It catches error and display proper message. The only question here is, why it ignores `YII_DEBUG` setting and acts like debug mode be disabled?

Comment: Ok, now I got it... maybe because you need to define YII_DEBUG before you include yii.php/yiilite.php?

Comment: I think you don't get it! :> Read the question again. The `YII_DEBUG` constant **is** properly defined and **is** correctly set to `true`. Only, for some unknown to me reason, Yii ignores it and acts, like it would be set to `false` or unset at all.

Comment: Are you calling a die() after the call to grid view. If you go through the comment section, there is a note about die.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging

Comment: @girish `die()` is a pure evil in PHP. I don't use it in production code at all and I'm trying to limit even its one-time usage for debug purposes. So, no -- I don't use `die()` neither ath the end of call to grid view nor any where else.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to activate this view for YII_EBUG in yii2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, because of [recent change in Yii 1.1.16](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3760#issuecomment-75040643). One need to put:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
    'errorAction' => YII_DEBUG ? null : 'site/error',
),
```

to application's configuration array, to have in 1.1.16 the same behavior as in earlier versions of Yii -- i.e. to have full-stack errors always rendered, when `YII_DEBUG` is set to `true`.